# How to create dir when uploading a file in PHP5

Tags: php

I want to make a form where I can upload a file to a directory. If it not existing I will create it. I want to choose where it should be placed myself.

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$url_link = "/gpsupload/tour/";
$dist = $root . $url_link;
if(!is_dir($dist)) {
echo"Create dir!";
exit;
}
if(!is_writeable($dist)) {
echo "Tjek writable ". $dist ." !!!!!<br />";
exit;
}
?>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
Select file:<br>
<input name="upfile" type="file"><br>
File upload to directory: <?php echo $dist; ?>
<br />
Or write name to new dir: <input type="text" name="newdir">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_FILES["upfile"])) {

if(!empty($_POST["newdir"])) {

mkdir($dist . $_POST["newdir"], 0777);
chmod($dist . $_POST["newdir"], 0777);

$dist = $dist . $_POST["newdir"] ."/";
$url_link .= $_POST["newdir"] ."/"; 
}
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"], $dist . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"])) {
 echo"File, ". $_FILES["upfile"]["name"] ." is uploadet. <a href=\"". $url_link . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"] ."\">". $_FILES["upfile"]["name"] ."</a>";
 }else{
  echo"File is not uploadet?";
 }
}
?> 
</body>
```

How do I select where I want to create the directory?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: RTFM... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mkdir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to create directories in php.